# Will Chaos increase if I let Hatters and Dead Eels kill each other

Tags: dishonored

In the "The Dead Eels" mission of the "The Brigmore Witches" add-on, a mob war is going on between Hatters and Dead Eels. Do I have to save everyone to keep my chaos low or can I let them murder each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't interfere, that's fine. Kills only count if Corvo or Daud killed the person. This does include indirect kills such as through rewiring arc pylons or feeding unconscious bodies to rats but letting NPCs butcher each other is fine.